# How to Get Data from 2 Json link in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

> code look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function updateDiv() {

            $.getJSON('info.php?hash=<?php echo $torrent_hash; ?>', function (data) {
            }).done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    console.log(item.size);
                    $('#sp').html(item.size);

                });
            });
        }
        updateDiv();
        setInterval(updateDiv, 10000);

    });
</script>
```

where $.getJson get data from different json like 
which is create by $torrent_hash

and its look like for first hash value

> http://localhost/final/info.php?hash=8195e4f6619ce780925d9952b358744dd81f1299

```
{
    "info":{
        "name":"War.on.Everyone.2016.HDRip.XViD-ETRG",
        "progress":0.02,
        "size":"706.72 MiB",
        "hash":"8195e4f6619ce780925d9952b358744dd81f1299",
        "peer":0,
        "speed":"0 Byte",
        "path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\final\\download\/8195e4f6619ce780925d9952b358744dd81f1299"
    }
}
```

> And Second Hash Value looks like
>   http://localhost/final/info.php?hash=5a1a5f86d71f46b53a2c4719f671555a0b33940e

```
{
    "info":{
        "name":"BOLLYGRAM 6th EDITION (UNPLUGGED) - (2016) DJ RINK (Remix)",
        "progress":0,
        "size":"64.59 MiB",
        "hash":"5a1a5f86d71f46b53a2c4719f671555a0b33940e",
        "peer":0,
        "speed":"0 Byte",
        "path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\final\\download\/5a1a5f86d71f46b53a2c4719f671555a0b33940e"
    }
}
```

> At console its fatch Both Data at a same time like this

```
706.72 MiB  sp.php:188 
64.59 MiB   sp.php:188 
64.59 MiB   sp.php:142 
706.72 MiB
```

> Here is my question when store this data to html "p" tag its show only last data 64MiB instead of both data

```
i use $('#sp').html(item.size); to store data
```

> I need Output Like

```
 size = 760Mib than
 size = 63Mib
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function() {
        function updateDiv(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "info.php?hash=<?php echo $torrent_hash; ?>",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.info.size);


                  $('#sp').html(data.info.size);

                }                 
            });              
        }
        updateDiv();
        setInterval(updateDiv, 10000);
    });
 </script>
```